# как получить номер итерации при переборе объекта в php циклом foreach?

Tags: php

как получить номер итерации при переборе объекта в php циклом foreach или массива, где ключ не число, а название, но надо получить его положение или номер итерации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вводите перед циклом переменную и инкрементируйте её в цикле.

Comment: а нет ли финкции для этого в php?

Answer (score 2):

Это просто заведи переменную со счетчиком:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;
$person = array(
   "first_name" => "Kevin",
   "last_name" => "Skoglund",
   "address" => "123 main street", 
   "city" => "Baverly Hils", 
   "state" => "CA", 
   "zip_code" => "90210" );
foreach ($person as $value) { 
$counter++;
// тут твой код
}
```

В переменной `$counter` всегда теперь находится номер итерации.

Comment: и для каждого масива перед циклом предется придумывать новое имя переменной или можно использовать эту?

Comment: эту одну  $counter

Comment: Ну получается обнуляй её перед каждым запуском цикла.

Answer (score 1):

Если без цикла:

```
$person = [
    "first_name" => "Kevin",
    "last_name" => "Skoglund",
    "address" => "123 main street", 
    "city" => "Baverly Hils", 
    "state" => "CA", 
    "zip_code" => "90210"
];

$idx = array_search("zip_code", array_keys($person)); // $idx = 5
```